# How to combine two displays in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have two displays. One resides inside a UserControl and the other one is a Rectangle. I am passing the Rectangle as a parameter to a UserControl method. Now inside my ViewModel Method, I want to combine this Rectangle with the UserControl display. How can I achieve this combined display?

```
ViewModel Code - 

   private UserControl CreateCombination(Rectangle rect)
        {
            //This UserControl contains one its display (basically a combination of few controls)
           CombinedUC combination = new CombinedUC();

            // I want to write some code here so that I can place combination object just above my rectangle (rect).

            return combination;
         }
```

Comment: You need to read a wpf book. All will become clear with some in depth learning.

Comment: A UserControl is part of the view, not the viewmodel